# In Illustrator, how should I typically set "Preserve Spot Colors" under "Document Raster Effect Settings"

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, spot-color, rasterization

I am learning Illustrator. Under Document Raster Effect Settings there is a check box which is labeled "Preserve Spot Colors". The fact that is unchecked by default is puzzling to me. Surely I would typically want to preserve spot colours and only uncheck it for unique circumstances ... or do I have a misunderstanding here?

Maybe it would typically be unchecked; but otherwise I would need to go into these settings for every document which uses spot colours and remember to check it. Can somone clarify to me why I would typically want it unchecked; and if that's not the case then what is Adobe thinking is in leaving it unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The only reasons why you would want to keep spot colors when rasterizing an image in Adobe Illustrator are:**

- If you print in spot colors (1-2-3 colors only) or CMYK + Pantones
- Or... you want to quickly import these color mix into your publishing
  software and don't mind merging the spots later

**The reasons why you would not want to keep the spot colors:**

- Your project will be printed in CMYK
- Peace of mind; no risk to forget a spot on a CMYK job

It's more a "unique circumstance" to keep the spots actually, since most print job (in general) are either grayscale or CMYK. But keeping the spot is quite a nice shortcut if your project is printed in Pantones only.

I just don't see why you would rasterize a vector if it's supposed to go for printing, unless you used some transparency or filter; the vector offers the best quality possible. And the pictures (photos) should probably have their Pantones and spot applied in Photoshop; honestly it may work in weird ways in Illustrator, I just don't do it this way!

There's not much reason to not convert your colors to RGB or CMYK when you rasterize them. If you're preparing a project that's supposed to be printed in CMYK, you're actually saving time by ignoring the spot and merging them with the Cyan-Magenta-Yellow-blacK separations. You also avoid making a mistake by forgetting this detail at the last minute, as it's commonly the case in print-ready files.

---

Just in case you didn't know, you can have special swatches of colors that use Pantones, but they don't need to be "spot." **And if you work with spot colors and plan to print in CMYK, you'll need to make sure they are not spot anymore on your final print-ready file.**

By the way, mine is checked by default. So that must be due to a preference setting somewhere.